# Show form result calculation after submit in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create an html form that loads data into a google sheet and after submitting and loading it to the sheet, I want to show in the html the result of calculating the fields. The calculation is in a specific cell in the google sheet according to the selected branch. How can I show the result after clicking submit?

Code.gs:

```html
    function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function processForm(formObject){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var branch = formObject.branch;
  var participants = formObject.participants;
  var engagment = formObject.engagment;
  var predictedValue = 0;


  if (branch == "On") {sheet.getRange('B2').setValue(participants), sheet.getRange('F2').setValue(engagment), predictedValue = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();}
  else if (branch == "Barak") {sheet.getRange('B3').setValue(participants), sheet.getRange('F3').setValue(engagment), predictedValue = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();}
  else if (branch == "Giv'atayim") {sheet.getRange('B4').setValue(participants), sheet.getRange('F4').setValue, predictedValue = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();}
  else if (branch == "Gilad") {sheet.getRange('B5').setValue(participants), sheet.getRange('F5').setValue(engagment), predictedValue = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();}
  else if (branch == "Ganim") {sheet.getRange('B6').setValue(participants), sheet.getRange('F6').setValue(engagment), predictedValue = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();}
  else if (branch == "Lahav") {sheet.getRange('B7').setValue(participants), sheet.getRange('F7').setValue(engagment), predictedValue = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();}
  else if (branch == "Magen") {sheet.getRange('B8').setValue(participants), sheet.getRange('F8').setValue(engagment), predictedValue = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();}
  else if (branch == "Oz") {sheet.getRange('B9').setValue(participants), sheet.getRange('F9').setValue(engagment), predictedValue = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();}
  else if (branch == "Rishonim") {sheet.getRange('B10').setValue(participants), sheet.getRange('F10').setValue(engagment), predictedValue = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();}

}
```

Index.html:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <h1>Enter your details</h1>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
  <label for="branch">Choose your branch:</label>
    <input list="magicHouses" id="branch" name="branch" placeholder="click here to choose" />
    <datalist id="magicHouses">
  <option value="On">
  <option value="Barak">
  <option value="Giv'atayim">
  <option value="Gilad">
  <option value="Ganim">
  <option value="Lahav">
    <option value="Magen">
  <option value="Ogen">
  <option value="Oz">
  <option value="Rishonim">
  </datalist>

  <label for="participants">Number of participants last year</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="participants" name="participants" placeholder="Enter the number">

  <label for="engagment">Parents Engagment</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="engagment" name="engagment" placeholder="Enter the number">



<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>


  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
    <script>

  function preventFormSubmit(){
    var forms=document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i=0;i<forms.length;i++){
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
window.addEventListener('load',preventFormSubmit);

function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
  google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

}



</script>
```

The field I'm trying to show is predictedValue. It can be a popup message etc or on another web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

##### From:

```
  else if (branch == "Rishonim") {sheet.getRange('B10').setValue(participants), sheet.getRange('F10').setValue(engagment), predictedValue = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();}

}
```

##### To:

```
  else if (branch == "Rishonim") {sheet.getRange('B10').setValue(participants), sheet.getRange('F10').setValue(engagment), predictedValue = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();}

  return predictedValue; // Added. This is important.
}
```

#### Javascript side: `JavaScript.html`

##### From:

```
google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
```

##### To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => { // Here, you can use the returned value from Google Apps Script side.
  alert(e);
}).processForm(formObject);
```

- In this modification, the returned value from Google Apps Script side can be retrieved by `withSuccessHandler`. Here, as a sample, `alert` is used. Please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Note

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#index.html_2)

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot. Is it possible to show the predictedValue on the web page and not in a popup message?

Comment: @Yael Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `Is it possible to show the predictedValue on the web page and not in a popup message?`, in this case, how about adding `<div id="sample"></div>` to HTML and replacing `alert(e);` with `document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML = e;`?

Answer (score 0):

As Tanaike said, you need to use a [success handler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers). One potential issue with your code is that it does not handle possible multiple simultaneous form submissions. See the [Web App Demo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153205/269219) for an example of how to do that.